# In Elixir, why is Kernel.put_in/3 defined in the Kernel module rather than the Map module?

Tags: elixir

When updating a value in a nested Map in Elixir, we can use `Kernel.put_in/3`

```
map = %{hi: "what's", up: %{my: "boii"}}
%{hi: "what's", up: %{my: "boii"}}

Kernel.put_in(map, [:up, :my], "dawg") 
%{hi: "what's", up: %{my: "dawg"}}
```

Why isn't this function defined alongside `Map.put/3` considering their inputs and results are quite similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kernel.put_in function works in any structure that possess Access behaviour, as per it's documentation:

```
@spec put_in(Access.t(), nonempty_list(term), term) :: Access.t()
def put_in(data, [_ | _] = keys, value) do
  elem(get_and_update_in(data, keys, fn _ -> {nil, value} end), 1)
end
```

Access behaviour is supported by both Maps and Keyword lists, so put_in is not exclusive to Maps, therefore is in the Kernel module.

Example of usage in Keyword lists:

```
iex(1)> Kernel.put_in([foo: 3], [:foo], 4)
[foo: 4]
iex(2)> Kernel.put_in([foo: [bar: 3]], [:foo, :bar], 4)
[foo: [bar: 4]]
```